# How does Samsung store pictures marked as favourite in the Gallery app?

Tags: applications, samsung, gallery, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I had marked a number of pictures as favourite on Samsung S10 Plus, I then renamed the DCIM folder to 2021_Backup (I had backed up my pictures onto a hardrive). After this I could not see any pictures in the favourites folder. I am assuming Samsung stored the list of all favourites somehwere and had a pointer to the actual image. Once I changed the folder named it lost that pointer and could not show those pictues. I have renames the fodler back to DCIM and that hasn't helped either. Something else is missing. Again, I am guessing the DCIM file got a different internal filename when I renamed it or something.
Any ideas on how I can get those favourites. I had spent a while marking them.

Comment: Your Gallery app might have identified the images, not directly, but via MediaStore. Mediastore is an indexed collection of some file types. Once you renamed the directory, MediaStore most likely reindexed all the files in it, so index number changed. Then, when you renamed back, index number must have changed again. These index numbers would always differ from the numbers your Gallery app used to identify, access and mark your images as favorites. Since files at such index numbers don't exist, your Gallery app can't show you favorites. That's my guess.

Comment: Goign back IMO is a lost cause. Your app would probably be having favorites entry in a database with files identified by mediastore provided indexes. You can verify this by looking the private and public app data directory of your Gallery app. You would need root access though. I don't have a Samsung device or I would have confirmed this already. BTW, are you using default gallery app or a third party gallery app?